# Trying to Add new Dialog Nodes to Watson Conversation but getting a error with response code 500

Tags: watson-conversation

Have been playing around with
 https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/#update_workspace, 
the update workspace API. Am able to change the output text on the dialog nodes, update goto values to null or deleting the jump nodes add new entities, add new intents. However Adding new dialog nodes throws an error. Has anyone else faced this same issue? Even updating the goto node to a specific node is is an issue.

Comment: Are you trying to add dialogs through Watson Conversation tool?

Comment: This should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42908862/api-watson-conversation-internal-error/42939982#42939982