# Api Watson : Conversation, internal error

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I am trying to use the **updateWorkspace** function of the Conversation API of Watson but I always get this error :

```
{"error":"Internal Error"}
```

My request looks like this :

```
curl 
-H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST 
-u "username":"password"
-d "{\"name\":\"Edubot\",\"dialog_nodes\":
[{\"dialog_node\":\"bonjour\",\"conditions\":\"#Bonjour\",\"output\":
{\"text\":{\"values\":[\"bonjour\"],\"selection_policy\":\"sequential\"}}},    
{\"\dialog_node\":\"Aurevoir\",\"conditions\":\"#Aurevoir\",\"output\":
{\"text\":{\"values\":[\"Au revoir\"],\"selection_policy\":\"sequential\"}}}]}" 
"https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api/v1/workspaces/workspace_id?version=2016-09-20"
```

The strange thing is that if I put only one dialog node it works great, but if I add two dialog nodes or more I get the internal error.

Comment: Have you tried upgrading using the Watson conversation tool?

Comment: Do you mean the online Watson conversation tool ? If yes, yes i tried it and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have more than one nodes in your dialog tree, you need to specify "previous_sibling" attribute in your node definition, otherwise the dialog tree remains undefined. For example,

```
{
    "dialog_nodes": [
        {
            "conditions": "#Bonjour",
            "dialog_node": "bonjour",
            "output": {
                "text": {
                    "selection_policy": "sequential",
                    "values": [
                        "bonjour"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "conditions": "#Aurevoir",
            "dialog_node": "Aurevoir",
            "output": {
                "text": {
                    "selection_policy": "sequential",
                    "values": [
                        "Au revoir"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "previous_sibling": "bonjour"
        }
    ]
}
```